# PrimeNG confirmation dialog can't be clicked, locks up screen

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, primeng

This code used to work at one time, so I think I've been snagged by an update to PrimeNG which has broken something for me. What was once a useable confirmation dialog is now hidden behind a gray click-mask which makes everything on the screen unclickable:

[image: blocked confirmation dialog]

The HTML for these two dialogs looks like this:

```
<p-dialog header="Save Location" [modal]="true" [(visible)]="showSaveDialog" width="350" height="190">
  <div style="height: 60px;">
    Save location as:&nbsp;
    <ks-dropdown #saveNameDropdown [(ngModel)]="selectedName" [options]="saveDialogNames" [editable]="true" [style]="{width: '200px'}"></ks-dropdown>
    <br><br><p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="makeDefault" binary="true" label="Make this the default location"></p-checkbox>
  </div>
  <p-footer>
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
      <button type="button" pButton icon="far fa-window-close" (click)="showSaveDialog=false" label="Cancel"></button>
      <button type="button" pButton icon="fas fa-check" (click)="doSave()" label="OK" [disabled]="!selectedName.trim()"></button>
    </div>
  </p-footer>
  <p-confirmDialog header="Same location name in use" icon="fas fa-question-circle" width="400"></p-confirmDialog>
</p-dialog>
```

And the code that launches the confirmation dialog looks like this:

```
if (_.find(this.app.locations, {name: this.selectedName })) {
  this.confirmationService.confirm({
    message: `Are you sure you want to replace the existing "${this.selectedName}"?`,
    accept: () => this.completeSave()
  });
}
```

I tried to set the `z-index` of the dialog higher than the `ui-dialog-mask` `div` that appears, but that didn't help.

I might be able to hack out some fix by searching the DOM for the offending `ui-dialog-mask`, but I'd rather not do that if someone else can see what I might be doing wrong, or has a better solution.

Comment: Try creating an issue at PrimeNG issue tracker and we'll review.

Comment: I'm not sure how to create an issue tracker (is that a Pro support feature?), but I did at least post this same issue in the PrimeNG forum here: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=56546

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in primeng dialog/confirm dialog. Some people suggested to use appendTo = 'body' to fix this however that triggered another bug as the code only append the dialog div to body rather than the whole native element. Here is my work around which seems to work.

Go to ClientApp/node_modules/primeng/components/confirmdialog/confirmdialog.js

line 73 change it from:   document.body.appendChild(this.container); 
                  to:      document.body.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement);

Make sure you use appendTo='body'

Cheers.

Comment: That does fix the problem (although for me I found the line on line 78, not 73), and it also fixes a problem I had when using `appendTo="body"` where the confirm dialog was shoved into the upper left corner of the browser window instead of being centered.

I don't want to rely on changing code in `node_modules` however, so I'm going to use a variation on your fix that I'll post as an addendum to my previous answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved this issue by adding `appendTo="body"` to the confirmation dialog as the following :

```
 <p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle" appendTo="body"></p-confirmDialog>
```

Comment: thanks. appendTo="body" worked

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue.
I found the root cause that we have used multiple ConfirmDialog.
Example: Using angular JS 
 - In file **app.component.html**:

```
<app-home></app-home>
<p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle" width="425" global="false"></p-confirmDialog>
```

- In file **home.component.html**:

```
<p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle" width="425" global="false"></p-confirmDialog>
```

So if we handle in the component file (app.component.ts) like this:

```
 this.confirmationService.confirm({
      header: 'Confirmation',
      message: `Are you sure?`,
      accept: () => {
       // handle except
      },
      reject: () => {
       // handle reject
      }
 });
```

This piece of code will trigger both ConfirmDialogs above

**Solution**:

Remove one in two ConfirmDialog. The ConfirmDialog of inside component is better. (In my example: The ConfirmDialog of **home.component.html** should be removed.)

Answer (score 0):

For lack of a better answer so far, this is what I'm going with for now:

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    const masks = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-dialog-mask');

    if (masks && masks.length > 0)
      (masks[masks.length - 1] as HTMLElement).style.zIndex = 'auto';
  });
```

This executes right after the `this.confirmationService.confirm(...` above. It's not a perfect solution because it doesn't put a mask between the bottom dialog and the top dialog, it simply causes both dialogs to be revealed with everything else below the two dialogs masked off.

Much better, however, than locking up the app.

UPDATE: A new solution, based on user860214's answer, as code added at the bottom of my project's `app.module.ts` file:

```
// TODO: Hack to be removed when bug is fixed in PrimeNG.
import { ConfirmDialog } from 'primeng/confirmdialog';

ConfirmDialog.prototype.appendContainer = function(): void {
  if (this.appendTo) {
    if (this.appendTo === 'body')
      document.body.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement);
    else
      this.domHandler.appendChild(this.container, this.appendTo);
  }
};
```